# XSL Create Element Which Has Colon in Name

Tags: xslt

This works fine

```
<xsl:element name="title">
  <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
</xsl:element>
```

However this doesn't

```
<xsl:element name="image:title">
  <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Please can someone advise? When I say it doesn't work, the page breaks. Unfortunately due to the nature of the system, I can't see an error

The top of the page reads as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:udf="http://www.virtualfestivals.com/udf">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is probably along the lines of `Undeclared namespace prefix {image}`. The "image" part of you element name is actually a "namespace prefix", just like how all the xslt elements are prefixed with "xsl:".

To resolve this, you need to add a declaration for the "image" prefix somewhere in your XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:image="my:image"
     xmlns:udf="http://www.virtualfestivals.com/udf">
```

Of course, what the URI is for your "image" depends on what you are need to add the prefix for in the first place. (**EDIT:** As per your comment, you will need to set it to `http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1`)

Note that you don't actually need to use **xsl:element** here. If the element name is static, just write out the element like so...

```
<image:title>
   <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
</image:title>
```

Read up on namespaces at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/ for example.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Google image sitemap - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en Ok thanks, will have a butchers